# Is zooming google map is considered as map load request?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

According to Google map license terms, 25000 map loads are allowed per day. Suppose I loaded google map on a page and this will be considered as single map load. My question is, when I zoom in or out on this google map, will it also be considered as a map load separately ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of service, not programming

Answer (score 1):

No...

A map-load happens only when you successfully create a `google.maps.Map`-instance(1 map-load per each instance, so when you e.g. have 3 maps in a single page it will count as 3 map-loads each time when this page will be loaded by a user).

Any user-interactions with these Map-instances(zooming, panning,etc.) will not count as map-load